# Sinatra & Angular $HTTP.delete 404

Tags: html, ruby, angular

Trying to delete from my API which is hosted on Heroku.
In Ruby file CROSS-ORIGIN is enable and I can get information from my API.
Although I have a problem when I want to make a delete request to the server.
I get an error 404 (Page not found), but when typing the url into the browser myself I can easily get this page.
cURL call works fine without any problems too.

script.js

```
$scope.DeleteData = function (index) {
$scope.id = $scope.companies[index].companyID;
var deleteUrl = 'https://*****.herokuapp.com/api/v1/companies/' + $scope.id;
$http.delete(deleteUrl,'DELETE').then(function(response){
  console.log(response);
},function(errorResponse){
  console.log(errorResponse);
 });
};
```

Ruby.rb

```
delete '/companies/:companyID' do
tempCompanyID = params['companyID']
company = Company.where(companyID: tempCompanyID).first
company.destroy
end
```

Html:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="companyCtrl">
      <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
        <thead class="thead-dark">
          <th>Company ID</th>
          <th>Company Name</th>
          <th>Address</th>
          <th>City</th>
          <th>Country</th>
          <th>Owners</th>
          <th></th>
        </thead>
        <tr ng-repeat="company in companies">
          <td>{{company.companyID}}</td>
          <td>{{company.companyName}}</td>
          <td>{{company.address}}</td>
          <td>{{company.city}}</td>
          <td>{{company.country}}</td>
          <td>{{company.owners}}</td>
          <td><button class="btn" name="_method" ng-click="DeleteData($index)">Delete</button></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
```

Chrome response:
[The response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f4YXO.png)

Comment: It looks like your Angular code is trying to connect to `/api/v1/companies/:companyID` but your Sinatra code is listening for `/companies/:companyID`. Are you doing some sort of rewriting?

Comment: To answer your question @Piccolo I use a namespace
found the solution my self.It was a server problem. needed to do configuration